# How can I make a command run once the next time I log in?

Tags: login, autostart, scheduled

How can I schedule a command to run the next time I log in? I don't want it to run every time, just once.

Comment: Add your command in /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: Similar to [How to run scripts on start up of ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really "ugly" solution, but you can add classic logon/startup script and after first run remove this script automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash

your command &
rm /path/to/script/yourscript.sh
```

The script will be removed, so it can't be started again.

(I'm sure there's a bettter solution, but I don't know it.)

Comment: This gets the job done. For insurance, I went with `mv "$0" /home/user/.old-scripts/` instead of rm.

Answer (score 2):

running a script has couple of options [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu)

I would try .gnomerc one, you can make it one time by making your script remove itself from .gnomerc once its done.

Answer (score 0):

This is already covered on this very site :
[How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu)

The second answer down seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: This question is about running it during the next log in only, not during every start of the system.

Comment: True enough. I saw the 'autostart' tag and took it from there.